# Pass local variable from one function to another in C

Tags: function

I have a variable that is initialized globally, but edited locally within one function, and the variable changes throughout the run time of the program. I want to pass that value continually as it updates to another function, so that I can use that variable within the other function. 
How can I pass the value of the variable to the other function, and have it update as the variable changes within the first function?

Comment: Pass it's address. But I'm wondering what "initialized globally" means. Is it a global variable?

Comment: the variable is global, but it is altered locally within the first function, so the updated values are the values i'm trying to pass to the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you've given the variable global scope (i.e., you've declared it outside of a function body), then you don't need to "pass" it between functions at all. Using it in one function will change its value in any other function that uses it.

If it isn't a global variable (i.e., it was declared within a function), then you'll need to pass its address. If you do this, you have to ensure that the function in which the variable was declared does not return while other functions are still accessing the variable, because it will have gone out of scope.

Comment: oh, i think it's an issue with how i'm displaying the variable within the other function which is meaning it's not visually updating the variable as i'm displaying it...I think i know how to fix that now. Thanks